# List names, size, and date created of files/sub-files?

Tags: vbscript

I'm coming from the PowerShell world so don't beat me up too much. I'm trying to list the names, sizes, and date created for files in the folder passed to the script but, I keep getting an error of "*Object required*". I tried googling and using the search function here but, I'm  just not familiar enough to understand this.

In my head this should work:

```
Dim fso, Arg, FolderPath, Exists
Dim Folder, colFiles, objFile
 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
Set FolderPath = Arg(0)

If Arg.Count > 0 Then
  
  WScript.Echo FolderPath
  Exists = fso.FolderExists(FolderPath)

    if  Exists Then

    Set Folder= fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
      Wscript.Echo Folder.Path
      Set colFiles = Folder.Files
      For Each objFile in colFiles
          Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
      Next
      Wscript.Echo

      ShowSubfolders fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

      Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
          For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
              Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
              Set Folder   = fso.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
              Set colFiles = Folder.Files
              For Each objFile in colFiles
                  Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
              Next
              Wscript.Echo
              ShowSubFolders Subfolder
          Next
      End Sub

  else 
    Wscript.Echo "Folder Doesn't Exist"
  end if
end if
```

It checks to see if an argument is passed, and if there is not, echo that nothing was passed. If there is, check to see if the path passed is a good path and try to list the files. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I still haven't included the size, and date creation property as I wanted to get this part done first before tackling that.

*Unfortunately, there isn't much youtube videos explaining the proper **If** constructs.*

Comment: FolderPath is a string, doesn't need the `set`. `FolderPath = Arg(0)`

Comment: @Flakes, ohhhh I wasn't aware of that! Sorry, my first day trying to write VBScripts. Any reason why it would throw it into my Else block?

Answer (score -1):

Give this a go:

```
    Dim fso, Arg, FolderPath, Exists
    Dim Folder, colFiles, objFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
    FolderPath = Arg(0)
    If Arg.Count > 0 Then
        If fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
            Set Folder= fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
            Wscript.Echo Folder.Path
            Set colFiles = Folder.Files
            For Each objFile in colFiles
                Wscript.Echo objFile.Name & " " & objFile.Size & " " & objFile.DateLastModified
            Next
            Wscript.Echo
            ShowSubfolders fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        Else 
            Wscript.Echo "Folder: " & folderpath & " doesn't exist"
        End If
    End If
    
    Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
        For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
            Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path
            Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
            Set colFiles = Folder.Files
            For Each objFile in colFiles
                Wscript.Echo objFile.Name & " " & objFile.Size & " " & objFile.DateLastModified
            Next
            Wscript.Echo
            ShowSubFolders Subfolder
        Next
    End Sub
```